# I am coding in python 1 11 111 1111 11111. But i am not able to go for the logic.Please give me suggestion

Tags: python

```
1
11
111
1111
11111
```

I want to get the output written above.

Down below, I have applied the code.

```
for i in range(1,6):
  for j in range(1,i+1):
    print(i,end="")
    print()
```

Comment: unindent the final line two spaces

Comment: Also you want to print `1`, not `i`

Comment: `print('1\n11\n111\n1111\n11111')` ... ?

Answer (score 1):

You've got the right idea iterating over a range. The rub here is that you don't want to perform any math. Instead you want to do some string manipulation.

You can repeat a string (like the string `'1'`) `i` number of times with `'1'*i`

So really all you need to do is iterate through your `range(1,6)` and print out `'1'*i`:

```
for i in range(1,6):
  print('1'*i)
```